# How to put color on -webkit-transform?

Tags: css, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I'm try to put color or background color on `-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg) skew(5deg);` but I doesn't try. Please help me.

I have this code of Sencha Touch:

```
.x-checkmark-base,.x-item-selected .x-list-selected:before,.x-item-selected .x-list-selected:after,.x-field .x-input-radio:after,.x-field .x-input-checkbox:after,.x-field .x-input-radio:checked:after,.x-field .x-input-checkbox:checked:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    width:0.75em;
    height:1.25em;
    top:50%;
    left:auto;
    **-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg) skew(5deg);**
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    right:1.1em;
    border:.35em solid;
    border-top:none;
    border-left:none;
    margin-top:-0.75em;
    **background: green;**
}
```

**How could change the color for checkbox/radio?**

The next image show

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a border-color instead of a background.

```
border-color: green;
```

Comment: Thxs, but didn't change color to **-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg) skew(5deg);**. I update my question. Thanks.